# Any tool that can make program runs under different user in Windows?

Tags: windows, impersonation

Say I want my program runs under predefined SYSTEM account, instead of the current logon user, do you know any tool that can help?

Comment: For the SYSTEM account, probably making it a service. You can always call your process from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ShellRunas** v1.01

You can download it for free here.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc300361.aspx

**ShellRunas** v.1.0 is a new Sysinternals tools by Mark Russinowich. It enables you to run a program with different credentials from Windows Explorer.

Usage:

```
     shellrunas [/reg | [/quietreg ] | /regnetonly [/quiet] | unreg | [/netonly] <program> <arguments>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a post explaining [running a CMD prompt as SYSTEM account](http://verbalprocessor.com/2007/12/05/running-a-cmd-prompt-as-local-system/), using the [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) tool.  Like the ShellRunAs tool, psexec was also Mark Russinovich; unlike ShellRunAs, psexec can execute command on remote systems & has more program options.

"run as" command might also work, but I haven't verified it for use with the SYSTEM account. Here's the info for ["run as" in 2000 and XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294676) and again for [Vista, 7, & 8](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Is it possible to run as system using this? I didn't think it was. Anyway, the winapi function for that is `LogonUser`.